# Apache having problems with PHP

Tags: windows-10, apache-http-server, php, services

This on W10.

I've been trying to replace a dysfunctional Apache-PHP setup.

I installed (i.e. decompressed) Apache2.4.57 under D:\apps.
I have a php version at D:\apps\php\php7.4.33.

httpd.conf ends like this (copied from a machine where things work OK):

```
# LoadModule php7_module "d:/apps/php/php7.4.33/php7apache2_4.dll"
# AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
# PHPIniDir "D:/apps/php/php7.4.33"
# AddType text/css .css
# AddType text/javascript .js
```

With all these lines commented out as above, the service starts. If I uncomment all lines, or the "LoadModule" line only, the service fails to start. I went to EventViewer: "The Apache2.4 service terminated with the following service-specific error: Incorrect function."
So enlightening, thanks Apache!

The file php7apache2_4.dll is definitely in place.

I also tried with PHP v8:

```
LoadModule php8_module "d:/apps/php/php8.2.1/php8apache2_4.dll"
```

And also:

```
LoadModule php_module "d:/apps/php/php8.2.1/php8apache2_4.dll"
```

... same problem.

Any ideas what I might have done wrong/should do?

***Edit***

Just found out (having downloaded the latest PHP version, 8.2.5) that "php -v" at a command prompt gives the following nasty message:

> PHP Warning: 'C\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\VCRUNTIME140.dll' 14.0 is not
> compatible with this PHP build linked with 14.29 in Unknown on line 0

... I can imagine that might stop the service from starting. Currently investigating what hoops I need to jump through now.

Comment: What do you mean? I've never used an Apache setup using an installation .exe/.mri, if that's what you mean (and if that's even possible). I've always just unzipped, configured and installed as a service.

Answer (score 0):

Yes... in this particular case I found I was missing "Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2022", available [here](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/#microsoft-visual-c-redistributable-for-visual-studio-2019), bottom of page under "Other tools, frameworks...".

After download, run .exe, restart... all working.